# Joining 3 tables using dbflow

Tags: android, sqlite, dbflow

I'm using dbflow in android app and have 3 tables (simplified for brevity).

```
City
int cityId (PK)
String cityName

Company
int compId (PK)
String compName
int city (FK)

Employee
int empId (PK)
String empName
int city (FK)
int company (FK)
```

I want to join all 3 tables and use these String columns as 1 result. What i tried is following example on https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/SQLQuery.md

```
SQLite.select(Company_Table.EMP_ID, Company_Table.DEPT)
.from(Company.class)
.leftOuterJoin(Department.class)
.on(Company_Table.ID.withTable().eq(Department_Table.EMP_ID.withTable()))
.queryList();
```

so my query look something like this

```
List<CustomQueryModel> model = SQLite.select(Employee_Table.empName,    
     City_Table.cityName, Company_Table.compName)
     .from(Employee.class)
     .join(City.class, Join.JoinType.INNER)
     .on(Employee_Table.city.withTable().eq(City_Table.cityId.withTable()))
     .join(Company.class, Join.JoinType.INNER)
     .on(Employee_Table.company.withTable().eq(Company_Table.compId.withTable()))
     .queryCustomList(CustomQueryModel.class);
```

My problem is that i cant find way to get Integer value of these primary or foreign keys.

Eg. Result of Employee.city.withTable() is IntProperty, but method "eq()" parameter must be Integer and I couldnt find way to get Integer from that neither any other way for joining tables.